# Gitlab CI/CD for Playwright testcases working in local, but not while pushing

Tags: gitlab-ci, playwright, gitlab-ci.yml

I am writing testcases for my project in Playwright.
I have used GitLab for CI/CD and my config file goes this way

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal

variables:
  RP_TOKEN: "myToke"
  RP_LAUNCH: "myLaunch"
  RP_PROJECT_NAME: "myProject"

stages:
  - build
  - test

cache:
  paths:
    - project/node_modules/

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd project/
    - npx playwright install
    - npm install
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - project/node_modules/
  tags:
    - karate
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - schedules

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - cd project/
    - npm install
    - npx playwright install
    - npm test
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - schedules

  tags:
    - karate
```

It's working fine when I run it in local. But fails when I push code to GitLab and give MR.

**The error message**

```
browserType.launch: Browser closed.
==================== Browser output: ====================
<launching> /ms-playwright/chromium-965416/chrome-linux/chrome --disable-background-networking --enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess --disable-background-timer-throttling --disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows --disable-breakpad --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-component-extensions-with-background-pages --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-extensions --disable-features=ImprovedCookieControls,LazyFrameLoading,GlobalMediaControls,DestroyProfileOnBrowserClose,MediaRouter,AcceptCHFrame,AutoExpandDetailsElement --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-hang-monitor --disable-ipc-flooding-protection --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-renderer-backgrounding --disable-sync --force-color-profile=srgb --metrics-recording-only --no-first-run --enable-automation --password-store=basic --use-mock-keychain --no-service-autorun --export-tagged-pdf --no-sandbox --user-data-dir=/tmp/playwright_chromiumdev_profile-U1WHRn --remote-debugging-pipe --no-startup-window
<launched> pid=461
[pid=461][err] [461:461:0216/070734.862628:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(234)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[pid=461][err] [461:461:0216/070734.862710:ERROR:env.cc(225)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
[pid=461][err] [0216/070734.882276:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(315)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
[pid=461][err] Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

Comment: I'm not a gitlab expert, but in the docs the image is inside the tests section https://playwright.dev/docs/ci#gitlab-ci Can you test that?

Comment: Tnx @hardkoded... I have tried that too.. But no luck..

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, one of the URLs was not accessible from GitLab. Changed the url, now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar issue. Ensure that your working directory within the image used in the pipeline is correct. Check with `pwd` the working directory used in the pipeline and compare with the working directory used local.